# How to retrieve type of function parameter externally?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a typed object with a function like this:

```js
export interface Example {
  edit<T extends Animal>(animal: T | Mammal<T>): void;
}
```

How can I access the type of the function parameter externally?
I've tried:

```js
import { Example } from './not-relevant';

type AnimalParam = Example['edit'](0); // This should be equal to Animal | Mammal<Animal>
```

*Note: The generics are not the main point of the question, but I've included them in this example since I'm using it in my code.*

Comment: You can't have `type AnimalParam = T | Mammal<T>` because `T` is unbound and does not exist in that scope.  If you do this [the standard way as shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WzajQm) you'll get `Animal | Mammal<Animal>` because the compiler will instantiate `T` with its constraint.  Does that suffice, or are you looking for something else (and if so, exactly what is it, since `T` is not the name of a specific type in your example code)?

Comment: are you simply search about this ? 
type AnimalParam = Parameters< Example['edit']>[0];

Comment: @RomainTAILLANDIER couldn't find that "Parameters" type while searching, that's exactly what I needed

Comment: If the answer with `Parameters` suffices, could you [edit] the question so you're not asking for `T | Mammal<T>`, which isn't an actual type?  Specifically: could you modify it to "this should be equal to `Animal | Mammal<Animal>`"? I'm happy to do it for you if you want.

Comment: Sure @jcalz, perhaps it wasn't the best example, I had to edit some production code to make it simple for this answer and I got that wrong. Feel free to edit it however you think it's better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the parameter type of the function, take a look at Parameters :
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype

```
type AnimalParam = Parameters<Example['edit']>[0];
```

Parameters<Example['edit']> is a tuple of all parameters of the function, and take the first with [0].